# Rails: SQL query make production server hang forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

It's all day that I am trying to figure out the cause of a strange bug.

I have this line of code in a model (which is invoked by a controller action):

```
# it always works
self.deliveries.create(subscriptions.pluck('DISTINCT endpoint').collect {|e| {endpoint: e}})
```

Everything works as expected (on my local machine, on the production server, and even with thousands of deliveries).

In order to *boost performance* I have replaced the above line with raw SQL:

```
# it hangs forever on the production server if you have many deliveries
inserts = subscriptions.pluck('DISTINCT endpoint').collect do |e|
   "(#{self.id}, #{ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(e)})"
end
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO deliveries (notification_id, endpoint) VALUES #{inserts.join(', ')}")
```

This works as expected on my local machine even with thousands of deliveries. However **on my production server** (2GB RAM / 2 cores) **this second version only works when I have a few records to insert, otherwise with 2000 deliveries or so the request hangs forever**.

To be more precise:

- **the browser doesn't get a response** and the HTTP request hangs forever
- **the deliveries are saved** in the database
- **the lines following the `execute` are never executed**

If I use a third version of code and I replace the raw SQL with the use of *activerecord-import* gem I get the exact same bug.

What can be causing this bug?

I am even wondering whether it can be the long output message generated (the large sql query) that crashes the application (I use logz.io).

Comment: Why are you involving Rails in this at all? A simple `insert into ... select ...` bit of SQL would be a better starting point, no?

Answer (score 0):

My suspect was correct.

The problem is caused by the `logstash-logger` gem when the log message is too long.

From the rails console I could reproduce the issue and I got (for one query):

```
LogStashLogger::Device::UDP - Errno::EMSGSIZE - Message too long
LogStashLogger::Device::UDP - Errno::EMSGSIZE - Message too long
LogStashLogger::Device::UDP - Errno::EMSGSIZE - Message too long
LogStashLogger::Device::UDP - Errno::EMSGSIZE - Message too long
... [and many many more]
```